# How can I improve performance for memory usage?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have some data:

```
MyDataType *deviceData, *hostData;
```

I allocated pinned memory for host data and memory for device data:

```
cudaMallocHost(&hostData, dataSize * sizeof(MyDataType));
cudaMalloc(&deviceData, dataSize * (MyDataType));
```

Then I work with this data. Each time step I upload data to CUDA, process data and download data from CUDA:

```
cudaMemcpy(deviceData, hostData, dataSize * sizeof(MyDataType), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//processing data

cudaMemcpy(hostData, deviceData, dataSize * sizeof(MyDataType), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

But this process is too slow. Copying data to CUDA takes about 3-5% of all work time. Copying data from CUDA takes about 80-85% of all work time.

How can I decrease data transferring time?

Comment: For me it would be important to know, what type of data you are working with. You can create a custom struct to store your data, you could use global memory to store your results and when you run out of memory, you save the results to the hdd. Do you max out the GPU with your calculations?

Comment: @semm0 My data type consist of some float3 and float values. I implemented fluid model (like SPH). I use results of each calculation steps for render my particles.

Comment: Are you really certain that you are timing and interpreting the timing of your code correctly? `cudaMemcpy` is a blocking call, but kernel launches are asynchronous. If you are not doing this correctly, the timing you measure for copying from the GPU may, in fact, include the execution time of prior kernels

Comment: @talonmies I hope I did everything right. I use this code for benchmarking: [my code](http://screencast.com/t/Glg17csFUw)

Comment: No you haven't done everything right. The memory copy time you are measuring includes the execution time of all of the prior kernels, and the kernel execution times you are measuring are actually only the API overhead of the launch and do not include execution time

Comment: @talonmies I suppose I must do [something like this](http://screencast.com/t/AR9IzYoanW) for apropriate benchmarking. Am I right?

Comment: cudaThreadSynchronize() is deprecated and should not be used. cudaDeviceSynchronize() is the correct API to use since CUDA 4.0 was released. But yes, you need to use synchronization if you want to measure the time in this way from the host. You could also use an API trace from one of the CUDA profiling tools

Comment: @talonmies Thanks a lot! Now all seems alright and data transfering time takes about 5%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem of timing and the asynchronous nature of kernel launches rather than slow data transfer rates. The timed device to host transfer was including execution of prior kernels because the `cudaMemcpy` call was the first blocking call after a sequence of kernel launches. We didn't get to see code of any substance in the question, but the solution is changing this type of sequence of API calls:

```
cudaMemcpy(deviceData, hostData, dataSize * sizeof(MyDataType), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//processing data by launching kernels

cudaMemcpy(hostData, deviceData, dataSize * sizeof(MyDataType), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

to this:

```
cudaMemcpy(deviceData, hostData, dataSize * sizeof(MyDataType), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//processing data by launching kernels

cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // host code blocks here instead
cudaMemcpy(hostData, deviceData, dataSize * sizeof(MyDataType), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```